# How to enable passwordless ssh for a particular program only

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a requirement where I want that user of my C++ program is able to do passwordless ssh on to a particular machine but the same user should not be able to do ssh on the same machine through a normal terminal/shell.

Answer (score 1):

On a Unix system you should make the program's executable setuid to that it can run `ssh -i` against an identity file otherwise inaccessible to a user running the program.  That identity file would authenticate access to a remote machine.

Comment: I could not understand your answer fully, executable needs to do setuid to which uid?

Comment: @Saurabh setuid to a user you set up specifically to allow remote access to the particular machine in question.

Comment: No that is not an option, as I need to do ssh on to remote machine through my program only through that user's id.

Comment: @Saurabh What does your ssh care what user it is running as, as long as you use the right username@remotemachine?

Answer (score 0):

You could hard code the SSH **private** key into programs source (or use a key chain - cleaner, easier to maintain), and then append the associated **public** key to the remote hosts authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 0):

Use private key authentication and disable other authentication methods on the server.

Additionally you may use the ForceCommand directive in the sshd_config of the server to only allow the given command to run.